# Outlook 2013 won't connect to Office 365 (Exchange)

Tags: windows-7, email, exchange, microsoft-office-365

I have a multiple users with a roaming profiles on a windows server 2008R2 domian. One of these 2013 Outlook profiles won't connect to Exchange on one of the computers.

Here's what I've tested: Let's say the problem is happening for User1 on computer21 (Windows 7).
I am connecting to Exchange for the first time:

1. I open Mail through the control panel and enter user name email and password
2. Outlook tries to find the server but fails

I move to Computer20, log on as user1 follow the same steps as before Outlook makes the connection to the server immediately.

I move back to Computer21 (Windows 7)
Log on as User2. Follow the same outlook configuration steps as before. Outlook connects to server no problem.

Log back on as User1 Follow the same steps again Outlook fails to find the Exchange server again.

The autodiscover record is configured correctly at DNS. The firewall is set to allow Outlook inbound and outbound. I have reset winsock. I have rebooted. I've checked email address and password by logging into OWA, logs in just fine. I've tried to repair the E-mail account by going to File > Account Settings > Repair.

Does any one know why Office 2013 running on Windows 7 won't connect to Office 365 via exchange protocols?

Comment: if this is more on topic at sever fault, I would request a mod to move it for me, please.

Comment: Please follow my answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/759635/cannot-connect-office-365-email-with-outlook-2010/784421#784421 - It works with 2013 as well. Just ignore the part about getting updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that it might be a user profile issue (either Outlook profile or Windows profile).  Try removing the profile and see if that helps (first try the Outlook profile then the Windows profile for the user).

***NOTE***:  Before you remove the Windows profile, make sure to back up the files first (the Windows profile hold user documents, Favorites and lots of other stuff).

Also, you may want to try and see if it will connect when you manually configure the Outlook profile for User1 on Computer21 (versus using Autodiscover).

Comment: The user profiles are roaming profiles. Wouldn't that make it so user1 would have the same user profile no matter which computer they logged into? There is no Outlook profile set yet, the first time you connect Outlook to Exchange, it creates the profile. My problem is that Outlook doesn't even connect to the Exchange server. How do you manually connect via exchange protocols?

Comment: No necessarily.  Roaming profiles add a complexity in that the _local_ copy of the profile has to be kept in sync.  Depending on the size of the profile, it may not be syncing properly.  I've had many a roaming profile become corrupted.  Just rename the directory on the server and delete the local copy (to create a new profile).  Also, to manually configure Outlook, use the _Manual setup or additional server types_ or something like that (when you are setting up the Outlook profile).  From there, you can set up the server type for Exchange (or Outlook.Com or POP I think are the choices).

Comment: I guess I could delete the local user profile and then add it again from the server. I know the profile on the server is good because Outlook connects to Exchange from other workstations. I'll give it a try on Monday.